# Can anyone give example of how to use Generic in InvokeAll() Callable method in java?

Tags: java, executorservice

I had two seperate taskLists and want to common / generic method to execute  both using  invokeAll() in ExecutorService . I am able to get the response and invokeAll() for each TaskList .
But unable to write a common to execute and get the result .

LocateUser Tasks :

```java
List<LocateUser> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
taskList.add(new BSLocateUserClient(url, locateName, username, token));
List<Future<LocateUserResponse>> locateResponse = executor.invokeAll(taskList);
locateResponse.forEach(response -> {
    LocateUserResponse user;
    try {
        user = response.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        //
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
});
```

LoginResponse Tasks :

```java
List<LoginUser> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String url : urls) {
    taskList.add(new BSWebserviceClient(url, username, password, isOciLogin22, ociWebServiceTemplateFactory));
}

List<Future<LoginResponse>> response = executor.invokeAll(taskList);
List<LoginResponse> loginResponses = new ArrayList<>();
response.forEach(loginResponse -> {
    try {
        LoginResponse loginDetails = loginResponse.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
});
```

Can you help me to resolve this ?

Comment: While the pieces of code might look similar, `LocateUser` and `LoginResponse` don't seem to be compatible in the way that you could make them share the same code. Also  your executor shutdown in `finally` looks really weird.

Comment: Is your aim to try and run them all together at the same time and get a list of mixed results? Or is your aim to write a generic method that does all the common things in those two methods, and call it once for each task list?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My aim to write a generic method to get a response . ```public T getResponse(){List<T> taskList = new ArrayList<>(); taskList.add(....) ; List<Future<T>> response = executor.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) taskList); } ``` like this - this method should be get different response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this one - by adding one interface `ResponseTask` and implements this interface to both response class and create a generic / common method for invokeAll and getResponse .

```
public interface ResponseTask extends Serializable {
}
```

**invokeAll** :

```
public <T extends ResponseTask> List<T> invokeAll(Set<Callable<ResponseTask>> callables, int threadCount) {
        ThreadFactory customThreadfactory = new CustomThreadFactoryBuilder().setNamePrefix("MultiThreadExecutor-Calls")
                        .setDaemon(false).build();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount, customThreadfactory);
        try {
            List<Future<ResponseTask>> threadResponse = executor.invokeAll(callables);
            return getResponse(threadResponse);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore interrupted state...
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

**getResponse** :

```
public <T extends ResponseTask> List<T> getResponse(List<Future<ResponseTask>> threadResponse) {
        List<BSLocateUserResponse> locateResponse = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LoginUser> userResponse = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Future<ResponseTask> response : threadResponse) {
            ResponseTask result = null;
            try {
                result = response.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // Todo Need to capture the specific exception to ignore here
                LOG.info("Exception : {}  occurred when calling multithread ", e.getMessage());
                continue;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Restore interrupted state...
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            if (result instanceof BSLocateUserResponse) {
                locateResponse.add((BSLocateUserResponse) result);
            } else if (result instanceof LoginUser) {
                userResponse.add((LoginUser) result);
            }
        }
        if (locateResponse.isEmpty()) {
            return (List<T>) userResponse;
        }
        return (List<T>) locateResponse;
    }
```